# Why I am not able to print alert message on click event of check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, onclick

Plz refer the jsfiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/17/

My code is as follows:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <table width="50%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" border="1">
         <tr>
             <td width="5%" align="center"><input name="chk_surname" id="chk_surname" type="checkbox" onclick="enable(this.id,'surname')"></td>
             <td width="10%" align="center">Surname</td>
             <td width="35%" style="display:none;" align="center"><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value-="surname" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

Following is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enable(id,name)
    {
        alert("hi");

        $(document).on('change','#'+id, function() 
        {
            var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

            var index = $(this).parent().index();

            if(checked) {
                $('#surname').fadeIn(100);
            }
            else {
                $('#surname').fadeOut(100);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Why i am not getting alert here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alert()` where is it?

Comment: jsFiddle does not work with inline JavaScript attributes such as `onclick="..."` and they are generally discouraged anyway... furthermore, there is no `alert()` in the code you provided here

Comment: I think you fixed your own JS - there were quotes missing in your alert on jsFiddle

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: So how to call that enable function on click event of the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/31/)**

- Select No wrap - In  in second drop down

[image]

- hi is supposed to be a variable wrap in quotes to make it string.

*Change*

```
alert(hi);
```

*To*

```
alert('hi');
```

Comment: just one more issue is there..
refer this fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/53/
in this when i enable the check box i am getting disabled text box but the table is getting distracted. I just want the table should not change its width.. only the text box should be displayed in third column

Comment: You probably need to increase the width also considering giving width in pixexls, http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/57/

Comment: I just wanted all columns width should not be changed.. if you see in jsfiddle the third column is being added in that width only means first two column width gets decreased..

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems in your code.

1) You're using jQuery v1.6

But [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) belong to 1.7+  update the jQuery version or use `.bind()`

2) `alert(Hi)`// missing to add quotes

3)You can assign **`change`** event within **`click`** event, but `change` event will occur only after the 2nd time when you click the `checkbox`.  so keep them separately.

Finally your code should look like

```
function enable(id, name) {
    alert('hi');
}

$(document).on('change', '#chk_surname', function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");    
    var index = $(this).parent().index();    
    if (checked) {
        $('.td_surname').eq(index).fadeIn(100);
    } else {
        $('.td_surname').eq(index).fadeOut(100);
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/39/)

Comment: Awesome +1 well noted :)

Comment: @Anand Jaju if you watch carefully your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/53/, you can see for the first time it won't work whereas when you click again it will add the textbox.  because you're assigning change after the click.  To overcome this try the above the answer

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the `enable` function is not defined -yet-, Try placing it above the html.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enable(id,name)
    {
        alert("hi");

        $(document).on('change','#'+id, function() 
        {
            var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

            var index = $(this).parent().index();

            if(checked) {
                $('#surname').fadeIn(100);
            }
            else {
                $('#surname').fadeOut(100);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>

.
.
.

<form action="" method="POST">
     <table width="50%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" border="1">
         <tr>
             <td width="5%" align="center"><input name="chk_surname" id="chk_surname" type="checkbox" onclick="enable(this.id,'surname')"></td>
             <td width="10%" align="center">Surname</td>
             <td width="35%" style="display:none;" align="center"><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value-="surname" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```